# For Emacs, long journey for using CTRL key in Android

Tags: android, emacs, keyboard, keyevent

I need some help with Emacs.  I'm running the Ubuntu in Froyo (Android 2.2) and connect with Android VNC Viewer.

But in Android VNC Viewer, it is hard to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>, `left mouse`, and `right mouse` buttons
so I made several experiments.

I tried to modify `/system/usr/keylayout/eve_qwerty.kl` (since my phone is `gw620-eve`), but I can't remap the volume button to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key, though I can remap the volume button to <kbd>ALT</kbd> key

```
key 114   VOLUME_DOWN       WAKE -> key 114   ALT_LEFT
```

I also tried changing `eve_qwerty.kcm.bin` file as well

Is there any special name for <kbd>CTRL</kbd> as like `ALT_LEFT`? I can't remap with `CTRL_LEFT` or `CONTROL`?

Could somebody let me know ASCII code of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>?  Or could somebody let me know how to apply this (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) useful reference to my work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for the CTRL key until Android 3.0.

Comment: I would be tempted to try to do some translation in the VNC client.  Or even make customized emacs bindings for the host.

Answer (score 1):

A related question at Stack Overflow is [Capture all Ctrl-? under Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337117/capture-all-ctrl-under-android).

For what you were trying to do on Android, there are [External Keyboard Helper Pro](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelper) app for physical keyboards, or the virtual [Hacker's Keyboard](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard) with Ctrl, etc. keys. A resistive or capacitive stylus could be useful with the full virtual keyboard in portrait mode if using a phone and the keys are small.

See also the EmacsWiki section [Emacs on Android](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsOnAndroid), with a recent first [Emacs port to Android](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zielm.emacs), etc.