# Android external keyboard ctrl keycode

Tags: android

I want to listen if the `ctrl key` is pressed but in `android 2.3` ,there is no `ctrl's keycode`.

My device cannot update to `android 3.0`

Are there any ways to solve this problem?

Comment: log the keyevent and check what is the keycode when you press ctrl. Not sure if ctrl is supported pre-HC

Comment: The keycode is same to the shift. They are both 59.

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities are mentioned in [For Emacs, long journey for using CTRL key in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124663/for-emacs-long-journey-for-using-ctrl-key-in-android) (Stack Overflow), such as [External Keyboard Helper Pro](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelper&hl=en) (Android app).